# Slider height is not changing with height property in react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

so I'm fairly new to react-native. I'm trying to implement a carousel with react-native-swiper.

Issue -

I want to set the carousel height to 150px, for this I set the property height to 150px, with this the carousel height got changed to 150px but when I try to render a text component below carousel, it is not rendering just below the carousel.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: { backgroundColor: "black", height: 150 },
    slide1: {
        height: 150,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB'
    },
    slide2: {
        height: 150,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#97CAE5'
    },
    slide3: {
        height: 150,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#92BBD9'
    },
    text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
})

const HomeScreen_ = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Swiper
                style={styles.wrapper}
                height={150}
                showsButtons
                autoplay
                paginationStyle={{ height: 8, position: 'absolute', top: 130 }}
                activeDot={
                    <View
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: '#c3383833', width: 8,
                            height: 8, borderRadius: 4, marginLeft: 3,
                            marginRight: 3, marginTop: 3, marginBottom: 3
                        }} />
                }>
                <View style={styles.slide1}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Hello Swiper</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.slide2}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Beautiful</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.slide3}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>And simple</Text>
                </View>
            </Swiper >
            <Text style={{ height: 100, color: "black", }}>Just a Random Text</Text>
        </>
    )
};

export default HomeScreen_;
```

[image: Carousel]

Answer (score 0):

you can check this sample, in React Native, we have covered any component using `View`

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const SwiperExample = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{flex: 0.3}}> // here
        <Swiper
          style={styles.wrapper}
          showsButtons
          autoplay
          paginationStyle={{height: 8, position: 'absolute', top: 130}}
          activeDot={
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#c3383833',
                width: 8,
                height: 8,
                borderRadius: 4,
                marginLeft: 3,
                marginRight: 3,
                marginTop: 3,
                marginBottom: 3,
              }}
            />
          }>
          <View style={styles.slide1}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Hello Swiper</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.slide2}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Beautiful</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.slide3}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>And simple</Text>
          </View>
        </Swiper>
      </View>
      <Text style={{height: 100, color: 'black'}}>Just a Random Text</Text>
    </>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {backgroundColor: 'black', flex: 1},
  slide1: {
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB',
  },
  slide2: {
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#97CAE5',
  },
  slide3: {
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#92BBD9',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
export default SwiperExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the **height** property in the wrapper object of StyleSheet and passing `containerStyle={{ height: 150, flex: 0 }}` as a prop in Swiper